# Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors installer Error

Tags: android

When I try to run the virtual device via the android studio,

1 - initially it says to **Install Android Emulator Hypervisior Driver for AMD Processors.**

[image]

2 - Once I click on Ok to proceed this window is popped immediately

[image]

3 - after the windows installer authentication an error is popped immediately as

**'CScript' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

[image]

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1** -  Restart and enter into the bios, enable Virtualization in the bios

**Step 2** - Then Deactivate **Hyper-v** and **hypervisor platform** in **"activate/deactivate windows function"**

I followed this Vedio as reference

*https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIBdY-5zr58*

**Final step** - reboot and start.

Below attached is a copy of the screenshot.

[image]

***I hope it works as it did for me.***